# Read lines in file after given string and store each line in variable

Tags: c#

I have a textfile and I want to read every line after a specific string in this text and store each line in a variable.

The text has this format:

```
[15-06-1999]
Brian
John
186

[26-08-2000]
//...
```

How do I read from below [15-06-1999] to the blank line and store the **3 strings** in seperate variables?

I haven't found any **efficient** method of doing this yet.

I'm trying to do this in C#.

Comment: `I haven't found any efficient method.` Where is your *inefficient* method? If you post it we can try to post a *more effcient* answer. In this form, it is just *write this code for me*

Comment: no magic way, just read lines, skipping what you dont want, stopping once you have all the lines you need. People might be able to suggest less or more elegant code, but the meat of it is the same

Comment: @pm100 there may be some magic way. for example an array that stores character positions from file. so filestream only needs to seek to that position and start reading from there. how ever this requires the file to be read once or have another smaller file which holds this guides

Comment: *I'm trying to do this in C#*. Great! You should have some code that you can include in your post to show what you've tried so far that isn't *efficient enough* for your needs. Please [edit] to do so. Without it, this is a *plz give me teh codez* question, and this is not a code writing service.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary looking at his text there are no fixed size lines so you cannot compute offsets a priori. That means reading the whole file to find row offsets. If I do that I may as well simply get the data I need in that pass over the file.

Comment: The question was put on hold before I could post my answer, so here it is in DotNetFiddle form: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CfYKuR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var path = "path to your text file";
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines( path );
int lineNumber = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++ ) 
{
   if( lines[i] == "[15-06-1999]" ) 
   {
      lineNumber = i;
      break;
   }
}

for( int i = lineNumber + 1; i < lines.Length; i++ ) 
{
   // These lines are after the line with [15-06-1999] do whatever you want here
}
```

Make sure you import the namespace by putting this at the top: `using System.IO;`

Here is another method (better) which will read lines as they are requested instead of reading the whole file. Thanks to suggestion from pm100.

```
var path = "path to your text file";
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines( path );
bool lineFound = false;
foreach( var thisLine in lines ) 
{
   if( lineFound ) 
   {
      // These lines are after the line with [15-06-1999] do whatever you want here
   }
   else if( thisLine == "[15-06-1999]" ) 
   {
      lineFound = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: file.readlines is better, it streams the lines in and so it wont read the whole file if you just need to work on the first 50, say

Comment: @pm100 Thanks. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I can not say this is *more efficient* because I don't know *your way*( BTW: do you really have a working one?).. But at least, this works....

```
var date = "[15-06-1999]";
var lines = File.ReadLines(filename)
            .SkipWhile(line => line != date)
            .Skip(1) //skip date 
            .TakeWhile(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            .ToList();
```

Comment: +1 , but my suspicion is that OP needs to repeat for every row cluster in the file, ie date row followed by n rows, followed by blank row